# Is there an international color standard for displaying readings

Tags: colors

I have an application that shows gauges for several different readings within a system. When the reading goes above scale, the gauge goes red.

My supervisor says the international standard color for when a reading goes below minimum scale is yellow. Is this correct? I was using blue up until this point and blue fits in much better with my color scheme.

If this is the wrong place for this type of question, could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought it would be green...

Certainly, in the UK, on an aircraft, when the temperatures and pressures are within limits, the needle is in the green section on the gauge.

Comment: Sorry, I meant below minimum scale. I've edited the question.

Comment: I'd personally hazard a guess at white, but that's not sourced from any sort of international guidelines unfortunately.